# Dispaying slitedata in edittext and textview in profileactivity and updating the data in profile

Tags: java, xml, sqlite, android-studio, android-activity

I have a login activity, registration activity, and profile activity. After I press the profile activity i want it to display user data in the profile.
I am trying to display data of sqlite database in profile activity in text view and edit text and update the data in the profile activity. Here is the code.

Here is my user profile xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".UserProfile">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="#fece2f"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <ImageView

            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/profile_image" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Username_profile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/profile_image"
            android:fontFamily="@font/alfa_slab_one"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:text="Ian Kipchumba"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/username_field"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/Username_profile"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profile_image"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:text="ian kipchumba"
            android:textSize="14sp" />


    </RelativeLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="20dp">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/full_name_profile"
            android:hint="User Name"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/profile_icon"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text=""
            />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/admission_profile"
            android:hint="Admission"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_adm"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text=""
            />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/password_profile"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_lock"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text=""
            />






        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_update"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#fece2f"
            android:fontFamily="@font/alfa_slab_one"
            android:text="UPDATE"
            android:onClick="run"/>


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my USERPROFILE.class

```
public class UserProfile extends AppCompatActivity {
DatabaseHelper db;
EditText name, admission, password;
TextView Username_profile, username_field;
Button btnviewUpdate;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);
    db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    //Hooks
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.full_name_profile);
    admission = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.admission_profile);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_profile);
    Username_profile = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Username_profile);
    username_field = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username_field);
    btnviewUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_update);

}

}
```

Here is my DATABASEHELPER.class

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME ="register.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME ="registeruser";
    public static final String COL_1 ="ID";
    public static final String COL_2 ="username";
    public static final String COL_3 ="admission";
    public static final String COL_4 ="password";
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE registeruser (ID INTEGER PRIMARY  KEY AUTOINCREMENT, username TEXT,admission TEXT, password TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
}

public long addUser(String username, String admission, String password){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("username",username);
    contentValues.put("admission",admission);
    contentValues.put("password",password);
    long res = db.insert("registeruser",null,contentValues);
    db.close();
    return  res;
}




public boolean checkUser(String username, String password){
    String[] columns = { COL_1, COL_3};
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String selection = COL_2 + "=?" + " and " + COL_4 + "=?";
    String[] selectionArgs = { username, password };
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME,columns,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,null);
    int count = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    if(count>0)
        return  true;
    else
        return  false;
}



}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please describe your problem more precisely and provide **only relevant piece of code**.

Comment: I want to display user data stored in the sqlite database as per the registration made by the user in the profile section and have provided the profile layout code, have also diplayed the database helper java class and the user profile java.